# Where can I find a comprehensive list of English grammar rules, sentence and question structures?

Tags: discussion

I need links to some websites containing the comprehensive list of English language grammar rules, all possible sentence and question structures, etc. for research purpose. 
Thank you.

Comment: Hello, Kshitiz, and thanks for your interest in English Language & Usage. Your question amounts to a request for a resource list, I think, and such requests are generally handled on the English Language & Usage Meta site. I will suggest that the question be automatically transferred there; if other reviewers agree with me, that's where it will live thereafter.

Comment: Alright @SvenYargs, thanks!

Comment: I have answered below in the expectation that the question will be moved to Meta.

Answer (score 5):

There will never be a complete list of grammar rules. Even the *Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* (Quirk, et al.), which weighs in at over 1700 pages, does not contain all the 'rules' that are intuitively known by an adult native speaker. Nevertheless, one book that does claim to meet your needs is *Complete English Grammar Rules: Examples, Exceptions, Exercises, and Everything You Need to Master Proper Grammar*.

It is different for possible sentence structures. There is a limited set of structures that are considered grammatical in English. So, for example, SVO (subject-verb-object) is grammatical but OVS is not. The following page on the *Grammar in English* site lists and gives numerous examples of the 5 basic sentence patterns in English: http://www.grammarinenglish.com/sentencepattern/?lesson=examples

Comment: However, there **is** a fairly extensive [list of English grammar rules](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf), with examples and names.